# using two database in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use another db in mongoose so I have this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectionOptions = { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false };
const conn = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/db_en", connectionOptions);

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const priceSchema = new Schema({

    fixed: {
        1: { type: Number, default: 199 }, 
        3: { type: Number, default: 499 }, 
        6: { type: Number, default: 729 },
        12: { type: Number, default: 999 }
    }
});

conn.model('Price', priceSchema);
```

Then I want to add data to the Price model in the new database:

```
const ggg = new conn.Price();

 await ggg.save();
```

But it returns this error everytime:

> TypeError: conn.Price is not a constructor

Comment: try to import it or require it like `const Price = require(**'path to the model'**)` and after that use it like this
`const price = new Price();
await price.save()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your model to an object in order to access it.
See the following code:

```
const priceSchema = new Schema({

    fixed: {
        1: { type: Number, default: 199 }, 
        3: { type: Number, default: 499 }, 
        6: { type: Number, default: 729 },
        12: { type: Number, default: 999 }
    }
});
var priceModel = mongoose.model('Price', priceSchema);
var price = new priceModel();

price.save(function (err, comment) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log('fallowing price was saved:', price);
});
```